# Binaries I created with pyinstaller are incompatible with linux

Tags: python, linux, binary, pyinstaller

I used the recent version pyinstaller with the option `--onefile` to create one stand alone file of my python script. On my Mac it works just fine if I open the file in the terminal (bash shell), but in the Linux bash I get the following error

```
bash: ./myprog: cannot execute binary file
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pyinstaller` creates an executable that will work on the machine it is run on. So if you run pyinstaller on Windows, it creates an executable for Windows. Same for Mac, Linux, etc, so I'd try running pyinstaller on your Linux box to produce a working executable for that environment. Mac executables are not Linux executables.

This is because (as I understand it) the underlying Python includes platform-specific implementations of certain things. For instance, the `os` module has a bunch of conditional, platform-dependent imports that will be bundled into the executable. Since it only has access to whatever binaries are available on the platform `pyinstaller` is running on, it can't produce a version for other platforms.

Comment: Ah, okay I see. So I would have to use pyinstaller on my Mac, Linux, and a Windows machine to produce 3 separate programs. What about Windows 7 and Windows 8, do you know if programs produced via pyinstaller on windows 7 would work on Windows 8?

Comment: @bluewoodtree My inclination is to think that they probably would, but there's no substitute for testing!

Comment: The problems are not the imports. See for example `os.path`. I'm on linux but I can import `ntpath`, which is the windows implementation os `os.path`. The problem is when dealing with specific system calls(e.g. `os.fork` which doesn't exist in windows), `.c` modules that must be built(and thus the executable will contain the build for the architecture where pyinstaller was run) and the fact that different platforms have different executable formats. Mac OS X executable files are *not* linux executables. The OP error shows this: the program isn't even launched!

Answer (score 0):

Linux checks magic number of executable file,
magic number of a Linux executable file starts with "DLE elf"

execute "od -c YUPUR_FILE" and see result